# what does the variable=${line%/*} do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script reading lines from a file.
for example:

```
while read -r line; do
if [ -f "line" ]; then
do something...
var1=${line%/*} 
var2=${line%.*}
fi
done < $file_name
```

what does the `var1=${line%/*}  and  var2=${line%.*}` do?
I have no idea...
Thank you!

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22828 have a look. it's string manipulation.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion and search for `##`. It is string manipulation on variables.